# How do I make a text block sit besides an image using flex?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to have an image on the left of some text, then another paragraph with the image on the right of the text blow it. But when I try to use inline-blocks or similar I end up with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVwK9.jpg
I want there to be a separation between the paragraphs. All the answers I found are pre-flex and also don't work.

This is my code, that I copy pasted from some tutorial website.

```
<div class="section">
<img align="left" src="images/placeholder.png"/>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
<img align="right" src="images/placeholder.png"/>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

.section img p {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use flex to do this? Also, can you turn this into a workable snippet?

Comment: It's just that it seemed to be the right tool from what I've seen.